# Do PeriodicWorkRequest and UniqueWorkRequest share the same Worker Queue if using the same Worker Class?

Tags: android, worker

If I use the same Worker Class, and same Tag for both a Periodic and Unique Work Request, will they share the same Queue?

I have a scenario where I want to perform an upload of data every 30 mins. However, in some cases the User might want to trigger an immediate upload too.

What I was thinking of was a PeriodicWorkRequest for the 30 min sync, and a UniqueWorkRequest for the immediate sync.

If I use a KEEP policy, same Worker Class and same Tag, and run a Unique Request, while a Periodic Request is running, will it queue the Unique Request to run after the Periodic Request or run it seperately.

What i would like is to sync only if there is not a periodic sync already running.

Comment: How did you solve this? I'm dealing with a very similar problem